# How can you track progress in Portal 2 Co-op?

Tags: portal-2

How can you tell if you've already completed a level in the co-op part of Portal 2? I thought it might be the bars (blue/orange), but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you go into the entrance for a co-op zone, there will be a little bar graph and lights for each player (blue and orange) that show which of the maps they have completed.

Comment: You can look either inside the room, at the monitor with big red buttons, or you can look at the display right above the course door.